# Why am i seeing the same error while I try to push my work to my github?

Tags: github, git-push

$ git push origin master
 fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Did anyone has any clue about this?

Comment: Do you have `origin` configured? What does `git remote show` say?

Comment: To get further info on the `origin` remote, you should definitely do `git remote -v` and double-check the HTTPS or SSH remote url…

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk ; Thanks, yes i have and it shows origin.